# UIButton's isEnabled feature does not work

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I am currently working on the `ios` project.

My problem `isEnabled` function does not work. Setting the value to `True` works successfully, but changes to `False` do not change.

What am I missing?

**My code use Swift5**

```swift
    @IBAction func nextScreen(_ sender: UIButton) {
        if self.nickField.text!.count > 12 {
            callAlert("long nick")
        } else {
    let url: URL = URL(string: globalUrl.apiAddress)!

            var dict = [String: String]()
            dict["nickname"] = self.nickField.text!
            sender.isEnabled = true
            do {
                try globalUrl.post(url: url, dict, encoding: .utf8, completionHandler: { data, response, error in
                    guard error == nil && data != nil else {
                        if let err = error {
                            print(err.localizedDescription)
                        }
                        return
                    }

                    do {
                        let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: [])
                        Log.Debug(json)
                        guard let jsonArray = json as? [String: Any] else {
                            return
                        }

                        if jsonArray["result"] == "Sucess" {
                            Log.Debug("Success")
                            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                globalnickname = self.nickField.text!
                                sender.isEnabled = false
                                self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "go", sender: self)
                            }
                        } else {
                            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                Toast(text:"error").show()
                                sender.isEnabled = false
                            }
                        }
                    } catch {
                        Log.Error(error)
                    }
                })
            } catch {
                Log.Error(error)
            }

        }
```

As you can see from my code, the function is changed to `true` when it is executed, and to `False` when it is completed. But it doesn't change to `False`. No problem found. Please come up with a solution

Comment: Your function seems fine, Does you getting success result ?

Comment: Have you stepped through in debug to confirm your `sender.isEnabled = false` line is actually being reached?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Hi your code was perfect no issues,

Please replace `sender.isEnabled` with `sender.isUserInteractionEnabled = false`   i think both are using  same property ,

i am testing in my dummy project both working same ,just try one time @thankyou

Answer (score 0):

Please check your code, `isEnabled` should perfectly work. Try to do it in a separate example without any business logic.

Or maybe share the complete code, otherwise we can just guess from reading your snippet.

BTW, sometimes running an Xcode clean of your project can be miraculously helpful  ..

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please create outlet of button and make button.isEnable false. It should work fine.

Comment: This is an output function. A function created by scrolling buttons on the storyboard.